# How does Verilog code run when it finds positive edge of clock?

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog

```
rd=1;
case1=2;          
i=2;          
n1=23;        
always @(posedge clka)             
begin           
    counter=counter+1;             
    if (rd==1) begin                        
        #5 window[i]<=douta;     //~~~~~~~~~~~ Statement1             
        case(i)            
            case1: addra=n1;
            case2: addra=n2;
        endcase                    
        #5 addra<=addra+1;       //~~~~~~~~~~~Statement2    
        #5 i<=i+1;            
    end 
end
```

The statements inside an `always` block in Verilog are sequential. At the positive edge of clock :

```
counter=counter+1 
if (rd==1) (true)
```

My confusion is that as `case` statement occurs first because `window[i]=douta` (after 5 unit time). After this statement 2 occur or statement 1 and statement occur at same time.

How do statements inside the `always` block in this case run?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the execution order should be as follows (in this exact order):

```
Time X:    if-statement
Time X+5:  case
Time X+5:  Statement 1
Time X+10: Statement 2
```

What you are running into is confusion about blocking vs non-blocking assignment. This is a nice example as to why it is called non-blocking assignment. When you hit the line `#5 window[i]<=douta;`, the simulator will wait 5 time units, then schedule `window[i]` to take on the value of `douta` at the end of the current time step. Because you used the non-blocking assignment operator, the execution of the `always` block continues to the next statements, which is the `case` statement. Since the assigns here are blocking assignments, they are executed immediately. Then, the `#5` is hit (after the case), so the scheduler schedules the next execution for 5 time units in the future. Then it moves on to anything else it needs to do. Finally, it comes back (still within time step X+5) and completes all the non-blocking assignments (like `window[i]<=douta`). Thats why you are seeing what looks like non-inorder execution of your `always` block.